# How to start with liferay

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, startup

can anyone suggest me the step by step learning of liferay portlet? I mean from where you can start? from where you can get help and instead of going directly to the middle  can we go one after another like a step so that we can use our previous learning to the next? I need to start working on it after 1 month.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay Portal is an implementation of Java Portlet Specification. Thus, the first thing you need to do is understand it. There is two versions of this specification:

- Java Portlet Specification 1.0 ([JSR 168](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=168))
- Java Portlet Specification 2.0 ([JSR 286](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286))

Here are a couple of links to step by step learning on this topic:

- [Introducing the Portlet Specification](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073645/soa/introducing-the-portlet-specification--part-1.html) in two parts
- [Understanding the Java Portlet Specification 2.0 (JSR 286)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsr286-141866.html) in three parts

After that, you may take a look at the documentation specifically for Liferay:

- [User's Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide)
- [Developer's Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development)

In addition, if you use Spring Framework in your projects, you might be interested in reading about [Spring Portlet MVC](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html), that supports JSR-168 portlet development.